# Is there a way to find a closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3} \cdot \frac{1}{16^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My problem, which was inspired by a homework problem, is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3} \cdot \frac{1}{16^n}$$

It feels like this should have a closed form, just like how [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Sum_of_the_terms) have. Maybe multiplying the two together doesn't make it impossible.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $ \sum \frac{ c^k } { 2^k \times k }  = - \log (1 - \frac{c}{2})$.

Now find the appropriate complex numbers (roots of $w^8 \equiv 1$) such that $$ \sum \alpha_i c_i^n = \begin{cases} (-1)^k & n = 4k+3  \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

From there, we can calculate that:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3} \cdot \frac{1}{16^n} = \sum_k^\infty \frac{8 \alpha_i c_i ^k } {2^k \times k}  = \sum -8\alpha_i \log ( 1 - \frac{c_i}{2})  $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
8 \int_0^{1/2} x^{4n+2} dx = \frac{1}{(4n+3) 16^n}. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Substituting this and invert the order of the sum & integral gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n+3) 16^n} &=&  8 \int_0^{1/2}  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{4n+2} dx \\
&=&  8 \int_0^{1/2}  \frac{x^2}{1+x^4} dx. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now factorise the denominator $1+x^4=(1+ \sqrt{2} x+x^2) (1- \sqrt{2} x+x^2) $ and do partial fractions etc ... Good Luck!

Comment: You've actually just undone the work that I did - my goal was to calculate that integral avoiding partial fractions. I was hoping for something else, but maybe a clean solution doesn't exist.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for undoing all your great work ... But Wolfy will give you a closed form https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28+x%5E2%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%2F2%7D%29

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4n}}{4n+3}$$ If you know the standard Taylor series of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions, you could recognize that it is
$$f(x)=\frac{\tanh ^{-1}(x)-\tan ^{-1}(x)}{2 x^3}$$ Now, the problem is to make $x^4=-\frac 1{16}$.

This, after simplification of the complex numbers, would give for your summation
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3} \, \frac{1}{16^n}=2 \sqrt{2} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3}\right)-\tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{5}\right)\right)$$ which is much simpler than [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28-1%29%5En%2F%284n%2B3%29%2F16%5En+from+n%3D0+to+infinity).

Comment: (+1) I am sure that $\frac12\log\left(\frac{33-20\sqrt2}{17}\right)=-\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}5\right)$

Comment: @robjohn. Very correct ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

We can use the cancellation identity
$$
\frac14\sum_{k=0}^3e^{km\pi i/2}=[4\mid m]\tag1
$$
to get
$$
\frac14\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{e^{(2k+1)(m-3)\pi i/4}}{m2^{m-3}}=\frac{[4\mid m-3]}m\left(-\frac1{16}\right)^{\frac{m-3}4}\tag2
$$
Summing over $m=4n+3$ gives
$$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+3}\frac1{16^n}
&=2e^{\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}2\right)+2e^{3\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{3\pi i/4}}2\right)\\
&+2e^{5\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{5\pi i/4}}2\right)+2e^{7\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{7\pi i/4}}2\right)\\
&=4\Re\left[e^{\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{\pi i/4}}2\right)+e^{3\pi i/4}\log\left(1-\frac{e^{3\pi i/4}}2\right)\right]\\
&=4\left[\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{5-2\sqrt2}4\right)+\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2-1}\right)\right]\\
&+4\left[-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\log\left(\frac{5+2\sqrt2}4\right)+\frac1{\sqrt2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\sqrt2+1}\right)\right]\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{2\sqrt2\left[\frac12\log\left(\frac{33-20\sqrt2}{17}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt2}3\right)\right]}\tag3
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice way, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1/16=x$, then
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{4n+3}x^n=\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n ~t^{4n+2}~ x^n dt.$$
$$\implies S= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^2 dt}{1+xt^4}=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{du}{u^4+x},~ t=1/u, x=a^2$$ 
Next $$S=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+a/u^2)-(1-a/u^2)}{u^2+a^2/u^2}du$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2a}
\left[\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(1+a/u^2)~du}{u^2+a^2/u^2}-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-a/u^2)~du}{u^2+a^2/u^2}\right]$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2a} \left [\int_{1-a}^{\infty} \frac{df}{f^2+2a}-\int_{1+a}^{\infty} \frac{dg}{g^2-2a}\right], ~f=u-a/u,~ g=u+a/u.$$

$$S=\frac{1}{(2a)^{3/2}}\left[\left .\tan^{-1}\frac{f}{\sqrt{2a}}\right|_{1-a}^{\infty}-\left .\frac{1}{2}\log \left(\frac{g-\sqrt{2a}}{g-\sqrt{2a}}\right)  \right| (1+a,\infty) \right]$$

$$S=\frac{1}{(2a)^{3/2}}\left [\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\frac{1-a}{\sqrt{2a}}\right)+\log \sqrt{ \frac{1+a-\sqrt{2a}}{1+a+\sqrt{2a}}} \right], ~a=\frac{1}{4}.$$
Finally, $$S=\sqrt{2} \left[\pi-2 \tan^{-1} \frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}} +\log \frac{(33-20\sqrt{2})}{17}\right]=0.324744...$$

Comment: Where is $\frac 1{10}$ coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, I  oversighted $16$ as $10$, I will edit my answer.